# getApplicationContext() returns null with Belkin WeMo SDK

Tags: java, android-studio, sdk

I'm trying to create an app on Android Studio that uses the Belkin WeMo SDK to control the devices around my house. I initialized the mWeMoSDKContext object in the onCreate method as was given in the documentation. However, when I went to run the app I kept getting a NullPointerException and after debugging I found that it was in the lines where I initialized the object. Is there any way to fix this? Also any advice on the app would also be appreciated!

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NotificationListener {

    private WeMoSDKContext mWeMoSDKContext = null;
    private EditText devicesDisp = null;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

        Button onButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        Button offButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        devicesDisp = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        TextView device = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);


        **mWeMoSDKContext = new WeMoSDKContext(getApplicationContext());
        mWeMoSDKContext.addNotificationListener(this);**



    }


    public class TextTask extends AsyncTask <String, String, String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            mWeMoSDKContext.refreshListOfWeMoDevicesOnLAN();

        }
    }

    public void onNotify(final String event, final String udn) {

        ArrayList<String> udns = mWeMoSDKContext.getListOfWeMoDevicesOnLAN();
        int length = udns.size();
        if (event.equals(WeMoSDKContext.REFRESH_LIST)) {
                if(udns.size() == 0){
                    devicesDisp.setText("No Devices Detected");
                }
                else {
                    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                        WeMoDevice device = mWeMoSDKContext.getWeMoDeviceByUDN(udns.get(i));
                        String tempName = device.getFriendlyName();
                        devicesDisp.setText(tempName);
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        else if(event.equals(WeMoSDKContext.SET_STATE)) {
            int numDevices = udns.size();
            if(hourlyPrice > hourlyPriceLimit) {
                for (int i = 0; i < numDevices; i++) {
                    String checkState = "WEMO_DEVICE_OFF";
                    WeMoDevice checkDevice = mWeMoSDKContext.getWeMoDeviceByUDN(udns.get(i));
                    if (!checkDevice.getState().equalsIgnoreCase("WEMO_DEVICE_OFF")){
                        devicesDisp.setText("Device state not changed for" + checkDevice);
                    }
                }
            }
            else{
                for (int i = 0; i < numDevices; i++) {
                    String checkState = "WEMO_DEVICE_ON";
                    WeMoDevice checkDevice = mWeMoSDKContext.getWeMoDeviceByUDN(udns.get(i));
                    if (!checkDevice.getState().equalsIgnoreCase("WEMO_DEVICE_ON")){
                        devicesDisp.setText("Device state not changed for" + checkDevice);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public void turnON(View view){
        ArrayList<String> devices = mWeMoSDKContext.getListOfWeMoDevicesOnLAN();
        int length = devices.size();
        for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
            String state = "WEMO_DEVICE_ON";
            WeMoDevice deviceState = mWeMoSDKContext.getWeMoDeviceByUDN(devices.get(i));
            String type = deviceState.getType();
            if (type.equals(WeMoDevice.SWITCH) || type.equals(WeMoDevice.INSIGHT)) {
                mWeMoSDKContext.setDeviceState(state, devices.get(i));
            }
        }
    }


    public void turnOFF(View view){
        ArrayList<String> devices = mWeMoSDKContext.getListOfWeMoDevicesOnLAN();
        int length = devices.size();
        for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
            String state = "WEMO_DEVICE_OFF";
            WeMoDevice deviceState = mWeMoSDKContext.getWeMoDeviceByUDN(devices.get(i));
            String type = deviceState.getType();
            if (type.equals(WeMoDevice.SWITCH) || type.equals(WeMoDevice.INSIGHT)) {
                mWeMoSDKContext.setDeviceState(state, devices.get(i));
            }
        }
    }

    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mWeMoSDKContext.stop();
    }


}
```

UPDATE: Here's the stack trace of the error

`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
            at org.cybergarage.upnp.ControlPoint.start(ControlPoint.java:976)
            at org.cybergarage.upnp.ControlPoint.start(ControlPoint.java:1051)
            at com.belkin.wemo.localsdk.WeMoSDKContext$1.run(WeMoSDKContext.java:125)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)`

Comment: Add the stacktrace of the error to your question, this looks like it should work.

Comment: Just added it, thanks!

Comment: difficult.. the wemo code isn't public as far as I can see, the upnp controlpoint one is likely trying to search for devices on the network. Not sure what's null though. Do you have network (internet) permissions for your app?

Comment: Yup, I included all of it in the manifest. By public do you mean within the code I posted or the sdk file that was downloaded for the app?